# Visual Studio Code quebrando layout de página do Jekyll

Tags: visual-studio-code, jekyll, markdown

Estou editando um arquivo `HTML` do meu blog do `Jekyll` no **Visual Studio Code**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao salvar o arquivo, o **Visual Studio Code** coloca o texto da referência do layout da página em apenas uma linha, quebrando a referência:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como evitar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava ocorrendo por causa da extensão: **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter**.

Então, a solução foi editar o arquivo `formatter.json` e setar a propriedade `onSave` para `false`.

Para fazer isso, segui os passos:

1 - Pressionar `CTRL+SHIFT+P` e digitar *Formatter*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Alterar o valor da propriedade `onSave` para `false`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para que a alteração tenha efeito, é necessário reiniciar Visual Studio Code.

[Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057725/turn-off-auto-formatting-for-json-files-in-visual-studio-code/40955632#40955632) do **Stack Overflow** em inglês me ajudou a resolver o problema.